# How to interprete the output of a Naive Bayes in the klar Package in R

Tags: r, naivebayes, bayesian-networks

I have calculated a Naive Bayes with the klaR package. The vector "RandomAssignment" is representing the 7 Categories. "ydf" is a data frame which represents the underlying data.

```
m <- NaiveBayes(as.factor(RandomAssignment) ~ ., data = ydf)
```

Now I get the following output tables. Can someone interpret my output?

Output
$tables gives me 23 tables. One of the tables looks like in the following example

```
$tables$CASH
      [,1]     [,2]
1 18.05122 1.155268
2 16.78024 1.738871
3 18.38182 1.003076
4 18.10533 1.347283
5 18.56694 3.707506
6 18.22490 1.487361
7 18.55957 2.067211
```

Furtthermore I received a table "$x" which has equal size as the underlying dataset (55X23). It is filled with positiv rational numbers between 5 and 25. How can I interpret this table?

Comment: This explanation comes from H2O: "The output from Naïve Bayes is a list of tables containing the a-priori and conditional probabilities of each class of the response. The a-priori probability is the estimated probability of a particular class before observing any of the predictors. Each conditional probability table corresponds to a predictor column."  Do you have 23 predictors in ydf?

Comment: My suggestion is that you demonstrate effort at searching for some answers to your question that isn't really about codong. Since it's an interpretation Q about a statistical topic the CrossValidated site (where this would have been on-topic) would be a good place to start but Google would probably work as well. This would seem to be a good starting point: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=naiveBayes+klar

Comment: @lawyeR Yes I have 23 predictors, 7 categories and 55 observations. But for the moment I reduced it too a small dataset due to performance measures. In the end I will have several thousand observations.Do I have too many predictors or too many categories?